# How to add click event to item on NavigationView of Android

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I am trying to implement Sidebar `NavigationDrawer` in my Android project.
To do so, I have used `NavigationView` in `DrawerLayout`. To show items I used menu. 
I want to add click event on that added menu items.

Code for reference:
In navigation menu -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_account" android:title="My Account"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings" android:title="Settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_layout" android:title="Log Out"/>
</menu>
```

In View:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. Implement the listener in your Activity:

   ```
   public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
                 NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
   ```
2. setNavigationItemSelectedListener in onCreate of Activity

   ```
   NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.account_navigation_view);

   if (mNavigationView != null) {
           mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   }
   ```
3. Override the method

   ```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
          // DO your stuff 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to make sure the Solution from Nizam can be found in Kotlin to, since it is takeing bigger place every day:

```
val mDrawerLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout

val mNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation) as NavigationView
```

Handle the navigation items in onCreate like this:

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { it: MenuItem ->
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.nav_item1 -> doThis()
                    R.id.nav_item2-> doThat()
                    else -> {
                        true
                    }
                }
            }
```

Remember: Return Type has to be a boolean!

Comment: Awesome, when I saw the Java version I thought that it would be hard to convert it to kotlin, but you've done all the work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(MenuItem item)` method.

for more check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java 8 approach with **smaller boilerplate** (**no "implements"** on Activity). Also helpful if your class is abstract and you don't want to implement this functionality in every other child:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  NavigationView navigationView =
    findViewById(
      R.id.navigationView);

  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    MyActivity::onNavigationItemSelected);
}

public static boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  if (item.getId() == R.id.my_item) {
    myItemClickHandler();
  }

  return false;
}
```