# How to go another activity by clicking Navigation item?

Tags: java, android, navigation

**Here I added my code. I have been created Navigation bar successfully. But Now I am not able to set onClickListener on my Navigation Item. How can I use a Intent on my Navigation Item using navigation item id . please help me someone. I need to know in details**

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <include
                layout="@layout/main_dashboard"
                />
            <include layout="@layout/lead"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

**navigation_menu.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:title="My Account"
        android:icon="@drawable/user"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notification"
        android:title="Notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_offer"
        android:title="Offers"
        android:icon="@drawable/offer"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_ticket"
        android:title="Tickets"
        android:icon="@drawable/ticket"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tutorial"
        android:title="Tutorial"
        android:icon="@drawable/tutorial"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_privacy"
        android:title="Privacy &amp; Policy"
        android:icon="@drawable/privacy"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/log_out"
        />

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // drawer layout instance to toggle the menu icon to open
        // drawer and back button to close drawer
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

        // pass the Open and Close toggle for the drawer layout listener
        // to toggle the button
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }


  @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

     if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
         return true;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkmg9.png)

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42499780/10153483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this in your Activity

> Step 1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
              NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

> Step 2  setNavigationItemSelectedListener in onCreate

```
NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.account_navigation_view);

if (mNavigationView != null) {
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

> Step 3 override the below method

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
       // DO your stuff 
    }
}
```