# onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) item ids are not matching what is in my xml of the menu

Tags: android, menu, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation menu in my HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity

The drawer opens and closes and the menu items show up but when I click an item eg logout

The ids inside this code do not match what is in my menu xml

i.e.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getTitleCondensed is " +item.getTitleCondensed());
            Log.d(TAG, "title is " +item.getTitle());
            Log.d(TAG, "item.getItemId()  is " + item.getItemId());
            Log.d(TAG, "R.id.menu_logout " + R.id.menu_logout);
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_logout:
                    App.getInstance().setUserId(-1);
                    App.getInstance().setJwtToken(null);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Logs show
getTitleCondensed is null
title is null
item.getItemId() is 16908332
R.id.menu_logout 2131230987

The menu xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_questionaire"
        android:title="Questionaire" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_dashboard"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:title="Logout" />
</menu>
```

My Activity looks like this

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private static String  TAG="DashboardActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

        // pass the Open and Close toggle for the drawer layout listener
        // to toggle the button
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // to make the Navigation drawer icon always appear on the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getTitleCondensed is " +item.getTitleCondensed());
        Log.d(TAG, "title is " +item.getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "item.getItemId()  is " + item.getItemId());
        Log.d(TAG, "R.id.menu_logout " + R.id.menu_logout);
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_logout:
                App.getInstance().setUserId(-1);
                App.getInstance().setJwtToken(null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {

    }
}
```

The layout is like this

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Dashboard"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this the navigation view which draws and shows the navigation drawer -->
    <!-- include the menu created in the menu folder -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu_view"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If `actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` returns `true`, you just want to `return true;`. You only want to check for the other IDs if the `actionBarDrawerToggle` method returns `false`. Basically, you need to move the `switch` to after the `if` block.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your actual setup, so I should also mention that `onOptionsItemSelected()` only handles options menu items. It does not handle any menu items that might be inside the drawer; i.e., it is not the menu handler for a `NavigationView`.

Comment: ok so im using the wrong thing?

Comment: I don't know for sure. Where is that menu being used? Posting just the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method kinda implies that you inflated it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: If this is indeed the menu on a `NavigationView`, you would set an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on it instead; e.g., something like is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/42499696. You'd still need the `onOptionsItemSelected()` stuff for the toggle to work, though. (I know, it's kind of a confusing mess.)

Comment: OK, yeah, everything before the `if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))` line needs to go in an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` set on the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Aah thanks so much for the help. Ill do that and see!

Answer (score 0):

Mike.m's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) comments were totally correct!

The problem was I needed the navigationView OnNavigationItemSelectedListener